# Remap NOTEPAD++ shortcuts in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

I am very much used to NOTEPAD++ so How do i remap my regular eclipse IDE shortcuts with NOTEPAD++ shortcuts

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust many of Eclipse's keyboard shortcuts by going to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys. You'll have to find each "command" and assign a keyboard shortcut to it, to match Notepad++'s shortcuts.